# How do I check that stream extraction has consumed all input?

Tags: c++, boolean, eof, istringstream

In the following function, I try to see if a string `s` is convertible to type `T` by seeing if I can read a type `T`, and if the input is completely consumed afterwards.  I want

```
template <class T>
bool can_be_converted_to(const std::string& s, T& t) 
{ 
  std::istringstream i(s);
  i>>std::boolalpha;
  i>>t;
  if (i and i.eof())
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

However, `can_be_converted_to<bool>("true")` evaluates to false, because `i.eof()` is false at the end of the function.

This is correct, even though the function has read the entire string, because it hasn't attempted to read *past* the end of the string.  (So, apparently this function works for int and double because `istringstream` reads past the end when reading these.)

So, assuming that I should indeed be checking `(i and <input completely consumed>)`:

Q: How do I check that the input was completely consumed w/o using eof()?

Comment: Not an answer, just a note: consider to use a tmp-variable of type `T` as you would override `t` even in the case `e.eof()` is false.

Comment: Do you get `EOF` returned if you do `i.peek()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) or [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to check what's next in the stream:

```
return (i >> std::boolalpha >> t && i.peek() == EOF);
```

Your version doesn't work for integers, either. Consider this input: `123 45`. It'll read 123 and report true, even though there are still some characters left in the stream.

Answer (score 3):

In many implementations of the standard library the `eof` will only be set after you tried reading beyond the end. You can verify that in your code by doing:

```
char _;
if (i && !(i >> _)) { // i is in a valid state, but
                      // reading a single extra char fails
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending on jrok's answer, you can use `i.get()` just as easily as
`i.peek()`, at least in this case.  (I don't know if there is any reason
to prefer one to the other.)

Also, following the convention that white space is never anything but a
separator, you might want to extract it before checking for the end.
Something like:

```
return i >> std::ws && i.get() == std::istream::traits_type::eof();
```

Some older implementations of `std::ws` were buggy, and would put the
stream in an error state.  In that case, you'd have to inverse the test,
and do something like:

```
return !(i >> std::ws) || i.get() == std::istream::traits_type::eof();
```

Or just read the `std::ws` before the condition, and depend uniquely on
the `i.get()`.

(I don't know if buggy `std::ws` is still a problem.  I developed a
version of it that worked back when it was, and I've just continued to
use it.)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to offer a completely different approach:
Take your input string, tokenise it yourself, and then convert the individual fields using `boost::lexical_cast<T>`.

Reason: I wasted an afternoon on parsing a string containing 2 int and 2 double fields, separated by spaces. Doing the following:

```
int i, j;
double x, y;
std::istringstream ins{str};

ins >> i >> j >> x >> y;
// how to check errors???...
```

parses the correct input such as

```
`"5 3 9.9e+01 5.5e+02"`
```

correctly, but does not detect the problem with this:

```
`"5 9.6e+01 5.5e+02"`
```

What happens is that `i` will be set to 5 (OK), `j` will be set to 9 (??), `x` to 6.0 (=0.6e+01), `y` to 550 (OK). I was quite surprised to see `failbit` not being set... (platform info: OS X 10.9, Apple Clang++ 6.0, C++11 mode).

Of course you can say now, "But wait, the Standard states that it should be so", and you may be right, but knowing that it is a feature rather than a bug does not reduce the pain if you want to do proper error checking without writing miles of code.

OTOH, if you use "Marius"'s excellent [tokeniser function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c) and split `str` first on whitespace then suddenly everything becomes very easy. Here is a slightly modified version of the tokeniser. I re-wrote it to return a vector of strings; the original is a template that puts the tokens in a container with elements convertible to strings. (For those who need such a generic approach please consult the original link above.)

```
// \param str: the input string to be tokenized
// \param delimiters: string of delimiter characters
// \param trimEmpty: if true then empty tokens will be trimmed
// \return a vector of strings containing the tokens
std::vector<std::string> tokenizer(
    const std::string& str,
    const std::string& delimiters = " ",
    const bool trimEmpty = false
) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string::size_type pos, lastPos = 0;
    const char* strdata = str.data();
    while(true) {
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
        if(pos == std::string::npos) {
            // no more delimiters
            pos = str.length();
            if(pos != lastPos || !trimEmpty) {
                tokens.emplace_back(strdata + lastPos, pos - lastPos);
            }
            break;
        } else {
            if(pos != lastPos || !trimEmpty) {
                tokens.emplace_back(strdata + lastPos, pos - lastPos);
            }
        }
        lastPos = pos + 1;
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

and then just use it like this (`ParseError` is some exception object):

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenizer(str, " \t", true);
if (tokens.size() < 4)
    throw ParseError{"Too few fields in " + str};

try {
    unsigned int i{ boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>(tokens[0]) },
        j{ boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>(tokens[1]) };
    double x{ boost::lexical_cast<double>(tokens[2]) },
        y{ boost::lexical_cast<double>(tokens[3]) };
    // print or process i, j, x, y ...
} catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast& error) {
    throw ParseError{"Could not parse " + str};
}
```

Note: you can use the [Boost split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp) or the [tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/tokenizer/) if you wish, but they were slower than Marius' tokeniser (at least in my environment).

Update: Instead of `boost::lexical_cast<T>` you can use the C++11 "`std::sto*`" functions (e.g. `stoi` to convert a string token to an int). These throw two kinds of exceptions: `std::invalid_argument` if the conversion could not be performed and `std::out_of_range` if the converted value cannot be represented. 
You could either catch these separately or their parent `std::runtime_error`. Modifications to the example code above is left as an exercise to the reader :-)